# how to find the indexes of element more than once in array of java

Tags: java

How to find multiple indexes of same element appearing more than once in an array of java. For example this array={2,3,54,67,9,9,13,9} should get me the result {4,5,7}.The code should be short too. Please do help me thanks in advance.

Comment: atleast show how you approached and what kind of error you faced?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not just iterate over it and check if it's the value?

Comment: all the codes are by far long because of iterating and saving it in new array..i wanted to find a shorter method

Comment: i am fairly new to java..so this is a problem

Answer (score 3):

Use `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`, e.g.

```
int[] array = ...

HashMap<Integer, Integer> hs = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
  if (hs.keySet().contains(array[i])) {
    // collision found
    System.out.print("array[");
    System.out.print(hs.get(array[i]));
    System.out.print("[ == array[");
    System.out.print(i);
    System.out.print("]");
  }
  else
    hs.put(array[i], i);
```

In your case, the output can be simplified:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) 
     if (hs.keySet().contains(array[i])) {
       // you don't have to print out all the indexes here,
       // you can, for instance, store indexes in ArrayList etc. 
       if (i >= 0)
         System.out.print(i);

       System.out.print(", "); 
       System.out.print(array[i]);

       array[i] = -1;
     }
     else
       hs.put(array[i], i);
```

Comment: how to display this hs?using for loop??

Comment: :shelly `hs` contains items and their last occurences, I doubt if you want to print them out (however, you can dor it in `for (Entry<Integer, Integer> item : hs.entrySet()) {...}`).

Answer (score 0):

Using just a generic `int[]` and `ArrayList<int>` to solve your issue:

```
int[] array = {2,3,54,67,9,9,13,9};
List<int> indexes = new ArrayList<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] == <value>)
        indexes.add(array[i]);
}
```